# Broken pipe error in Python hosted webserver

Tags: python, reactjs, webserver, web-hosting, broken-pipe

I am hosting my server on python and have written the following code,

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

webServer = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', port),
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

webServer.socket =ssl.wrap_socket(webServer.socket,keyfile="keyfile",certfile='certfile',server_side=True)

print('Server is listening now.....')

webServer.serve_forever()
```

This is throwing error as below,

```
code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x02
error:[Errno 32] Broken pipe.
```

I did some research and found that the ssl connection is getting closed first and then the response is coming up due to which its throwing this exception.
The solution what I have found is below

```
try:
    # The code mentioned above
except IOError, e:
    if e.errno == errno.EPIPE:
        # How to handle, what should be here
```

In the above solution how do we handle the error. Do we need to reopen the connection?

Comment: I just want to add that this is happening at the load of page when its loading all the static images.